# Mongoose API get nested items in array by _id

Tags: node.js, api, express, request, mongoose

I am building an api with Express and Mongoose (Backbone on the front). I have a Mongoose User model that contains an array called "orders". I need to set up a create method that will READ a Single Order by ID.

When I navigate to:

```
http://localhost:3000/test/
```

I get the following for a logged in user:

```
{
  "__v": 0,
  "_id": "537d09a1fe47a00000c54514",
  "kittenType": "Grumpy",
  "local": {
    "petname": "Smeagol",
    "password": "$2a$08$X4sF5UmYZ3/2cxfRzpPcq.pphYFRKcb.6xBGupdUyUMgWJlFSr/uq",
    "email": "julie@gmail.com"
  },

  "orders": [
    {
      "title": "Big Max Fountain",
      "description": "Large capacity drinking fountain",
      "quantity": "2",
      "price": 500,
      "_id": "53837e9e681808e6ea9f9ca4",
      "modified": "2014-05-28T23:49:10.232Z"
    },
    {
      "title": "Lotus Fountain",
      "description": "Tranquil pools of water",
      "quantity": "1",
      "price": 1000,
      "_id": "53867762ff514df026b608fa",
      "modified": "2014-05-28T23:55:16.263Z"
    }
  ]
}
```

When I navigate to:

```
http://localhost:3000/test/orders
```

I send the list of orders for the logged in user (this gives me the array of orders:

```
app.get('/test/orders', function(req, res) {
  User.findOne({'_id': req.user.id }, function(err, user) {
    if (err)
      return done(err);

    if (user) {
      res.send(user.orders);

    }

  });
});
```

How do I then send each order by id?

```
app.get('/test/orders/:id', function(req, res) {
  User.findOne({'_id': req.user.id }, function(err, user) {
    if (err)
      return done(err);

    if (user) {

      //send the order by id here thru the url

    }
  });
});
```

ADDED AFTER RESPONSE:

```
var userSchema = mongoose.Schema({

user            : {
    type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId,
    ref: 'User'
},
orders: [{
    title: String,  
    description: String, 
    quantity : String,
    price : Number,
    modified: { type: Date, default: Date.now }
}],
signup: [{
    name: String,
    courseDay: String,
    time: String,
    location: String,
    modified: { type: Date, default: Date.now }
}],

kittenType   : String,
profilePhoto : String,
profilePage :  String,
local            : {
    email        : String,
    password     : String,
    petname      : String,
    path         : String,

}
```

routes:

```
app.get('/test', function(req,res) {
res.send(res.locals.user);
});

app.get('/test/orders', function(req, res) {
User.findOne({'_id': req.user.id }, function(err, user) {
    if (err) 
        return done(err);

    if (user) {
        res.send(user.orders);

    }

});
});

app.post('/api/orders', isLoggedIn, function (req, res){

User.findOne({'_id': req.user.id }, function(err, user) {
    if (err)
        return done(err);

    if (user) {
        user.orders.quantity = req.body.quantity;
        user.orders.description = req.body.description;
        user.orders.title = req.body.title;
        user.orders.price = req.body.price;
        user.orders.modified = req.body.modified;


        user.update({$push: { "orders" : 
            {   title: user.orders.title,
                description: user.orders.description,
                quantity: user.orders.quantity,
                price: user.orders.price,
                modified: user.orders.modified
            }
            }},{safe:true, upsert:true},function(err){
                if(err){
                    console.log(err);
                } else{
                    console.log("Successfully added" + user.orders);
                }
        });

        console.log('located a user');
    }       
});

});
```

WORKING GET METHOD:

```
app.get('/test/orders/:id', function(req, res) {
  User.findOne({'_id': req.user.id }, function(err, user) {
    if (err)
      return done(err);
    if (user) {
      console.log(user.orders);
      var order = user.orders.filter(function(e){ return e._id == req.params.id })[0]
      console.log(order);
      res.send(order);
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you don't need to find a user in this case. Enough to find `Order` with proper condition:

```
app.get('/test/orders/:id', function(req, res) {
  Order.findOne({'_id': req.params.id, 'user_id': req.user.id }, function(err, order) {
    if (err)
      return done(err);
    if (order) {
      res.send(order);
    }
  });
});
```

But you should log `req` to be sure that you use proper `id`s. It depends also on your routes, that you didn't public.

Or if you need to find `User` model, you can simply use filter method. Code will be almost the same as in first method:

```
app.get('/test/orders/:id', function(req, res) {
  User.findOne({'_id': req.user.id }, function(err, user) {
    if (err)
      return done(err);
    if (user) {
      console.log(user.orders); // returns an array
      // console.log(req.id); // to be sure that it returns proper order id
      // perhaps it could be next
      console.log(req.params.id);

      var order_id = user.orders.filter(function(e){ return e == req.params.id })[0]

      // then find this order
      Order.findOne({'_id': order_id }, function(err1, order) {
        if (err1)
          return done(err1);
        if (order) {
          res.send(order);
        }
      });
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your response! I tried method 1 and got: ReferenceError: Order is not defined. When I tried method 2 I got:  user.orders.filter(function(e){ return e._id == req.order.id })[0]
                                                               ^
TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined

I do not have a separate schema for orders - it is part of my user model ... I am adding the schema and routes to my original code now at the bottom...

Comment: Ok, you should show me your routes then, cause looks like them doesn't  contains `order_id` or perhaps there is exactly `req.order_id`

Comment: added. let me know if you wanted to see anything else

Comment: Ok, thanks, i updated my answer. I recommend you to `console.log(req);` to be sure that it contains proper info.

Comment: console.log(req); does return the correct info (including the orders array), but console.log(req.orders) returns undefined ... why would this be?

Comment: Add it to post. I said it should be just `req.id` there is no `req.orders` in your requst. I've updated all code to this id, have you tried it?

Comment: Option 1: ReferenceError: Order is not defined
Option 2: ( which I think is the approach I need to take) just hangs ... nothing happens, pages doesn't load; no message in the console.

Comment: Yep, i changed 2nd method. Forgot to send response.

Comment: console.log(req.id); came back undefined

app.get('/test/orders/:id', function(req, res) {

 User.findOne({'_id': req.user.id }, function(err, user) {
    if (err)
      return done(err);
    if (user) {
      console.log(req.id);
    
    }
  });
});

Comment: Check out `user.orders` it perhaps contains only `id`s. Then you should request `Order`

Comment: from your last update: console.log(user.orders) sends the array, console.log(order) returns undefined.  I am not sure what you mean by "perhaps contains only ids." ?

Comment: I looked up my code, and order id can be `req.params.id`

Comment: The old version of option 2 worked when i added in "req.params.id". I am posting the code that worked at the bottom of my original post. 
THANK YOU!